Проверка textarea, что он содержит определенное число, тогда button активный
Подскажите, как сделать простую проверку на JS?
Нужно, чтобы если textarea содержит, например, число 37, тогда кнопка button - была активна, а если любое другое значение - кнопка была не активна.

Для того, что бы проверить содержимое textarea на конкретное значение, надо повесить обработчик ввода данных на сам textarea и проверять, удовлетворяет ли условию введенное значение


const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const area = document.getElementById('txt');

area.addEventListener('input', () => {
  btn.disabled = area.value !== '37'
})
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<br />
<button id="btn" disabled>Кнопка</button>




Большое спасибо!
